# Open color picker when editing CSS in WebStorm

Tags: css, webstorm

Given I'm editing CSS in WebStorm, how can I open a color picker ?

For example

```
.bar {
    backround: // shortcut to open color picker that will fill in HEX value
}
```

Comment: i think you have to set a keybind on your own for this

Comment: what's the name of the action

Comment: see megamit answer

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple ways of doing this.

If you are editing webstorm should prompt you with autocompletions that look like this:

[image: Screenshot of the appearance of webstorm]

Here pressing enter will allow you to open the colour picker. If auto complete does not manually appear you can press `ctrl + space` to request it to appear.

If you want to directly open the colour picker from anywhere you will need to assign a key bind to `Show color picker` in settings. However i find that it does not output the result into the editor if invoked this way.

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1.** First of all, check that "[Gutter Icons](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/settings-gutter-icons.html)" is enabled in your IDE !

**Case 2.** This solution is for rare situations, e.g. editing React|Native JSX+SVG+TS and when "Gutter Icons" occasionally didn't appeared:

1. Invoke color picker even it not proposed by IDE:

[image]

2. Select HEX value in your code. Yellow balloon on the left
   will appear:

[image]

3. Profit!

[image]